# R plot marginal effects in lme

Tags: r, nlme, marginal-effects

I have the following lme model (intercepts random on 3 levels):

- Y=dependent V.,
- V1-V3=individual level variables (level 1),
- V4=Country level variable (level 3)

random slope for V1
cross-level interaction of V1 and V4

```
modelCI1= lme(Y~ V1+V2+V3+V1*V4+V4,
            data=total,
            method="ML",
            na.action="na.omit",
            random=list(~1|level2,~V1|level3),
            control=lmeControl(msMaxIter = 200))
```

I would like to plot the marginal effects of V1 for each level of V4.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/). This should work:

```
library(ggeffects)
p <- ggpredict(nodelCI1, c("V1", "V4"))
plot(p)
```

Details can be found in the *Articles* from the above linked website.